# Magento2: How to export product SKUs along with their respective image URLs

Tags: product, image, url-key

I use magento on a basic level for my work.

I was wondering if there is a way to export all the data onto a spreadsheet, including data from all the products on the site, especially the product codes, the image URL links, and a link to the product page.

Answer (score 0):

Magento on default the exports features which you can use to exports all the products on your store. On the admin dash borad you can follow the path and check it:

```
Admin Dashboard-> System > Data Transfer > Export
```

Below are the links for reference:

1. https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/systems/data-transfer/data-export.html?lang=en
2. https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/export-products-all-data-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

for advanced export of all product fields (or particular selected fields) you can use Store Manager for Magento (there's a trial available for testing)